# How to add workbox to React post update

Tags: reactjs, service-worker, workbox, workbox-webpack-plugin

I have decided to try to use workbox but all of the guides i have seen talk about integrating with the service worker that react makes.

But when i install a CRA i no longer get the service worker made for me. What do i need to do to integrate workbox here?

This is my current code:

App.js

```
    import React from 'react';
    import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
    import App from './App';
    import swDev from './swDev'
     
    ReactDOM.render(
      <React.StrictMode>
        <App />
      </React.StrictMode>,
      document.getElementById('root')
    );
    
    swDev()
```

swDev.js

```
    export default function swDev(){
      let swURL = `${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/sw.js`;
      if('serviceWorker' in navigator){
        navigator.serviceWorker.register(swURL).then(res => {
          console.log('Service worker has been registered');
        }).catch(err => console.log('Service worker was not registered'))
      }
    }
```

then this is the service worker in the public file

```
const cacheVersion = 'v1'


self.addEventListener('install', ()=>{
  console.log('Service worker has been installed');
})

self.addEventListener('activate', ()=>{
  console.log('Service worker is being activated');


})

self.addEventListener('fetch',(e)=>{

  e.respondWith(handleRequest(e.request))

  // function to update the cache
  // updateCache(e.request)

})


async function handleRequest(req){
  const cache = await caches.open(cacheVersion)
  const cacheRes = await cache.match(req)
  if(cacheRes){
    return cacheRes;
  }else{
    const netRes = await fetch(req);
    console.log(netRes);

    if(netRes.ok){
      return netRes;
    }else{
      // return an error message or something by matching it to a 404 page
      return netRes;
    }
  }
}

async function updateCache(req){

  if(navigator.onLine){
    const res = await fetch(req);
    const cache = await caches.open(cacheVersion);

    if(res.ok){
      // add the response to the caches and return the response
      await cache.put(req, res.clone())
    }

  }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

`create-react-app` v4 will [check for the presence](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/282c03f9525fdf8061ffa1ec50dce89296d916bd/packages/react-scripts/config/webpack.config.js#L709-L721) of a `src/service-worker.js` file at build time, and if found, run `workbox-webpack-plugin`'s [`InjectManifest` plugin](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/modules/workbox-webpack-plugin#injectmanifest_plugin), passing in that file as the `swSrc` parameter.

If you're starting a new project and follow the instruction from `create-react-app`'s "[Making a Progressive Web App](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/making-a-progressive-web-app/)" guide, i.e. you run `npx create-react-app my-app --template cra-template-pwa`, you'll end up with everything in the right place.

Which is to say your project will:

- automatically [bundle](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/guides/using-bundlers) the code in `src/service-worker.js` (transforming the ES module imports into code that can be run inside the service worker)
- look for the symbol `self.__WB_MANIFEST` somewhere inside your `src/service-worker.js`, and replace it with a [precache manifest](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/modules/workbox-precaching#explanation_of_the_precache_list), consisting of URLs and revision info about all your `webpack` assets, so that Workbox can precache them.

If you're not interested in precaching your `webpack` assets, then you don't need to use the `InjectManifest` plugin at all, and you can just put whatever code you want in a file named *anything other than* `src/service-worker.js`, and register that file as your service worker. That's up to you.

If you are interested in Workbox's precaching, but you're upgrading from an older `create-react-app` and you don't have a "correct" `src/service-worker.js` file, you can manually copy the [file from the template](https://github.com/cra-template/pwa/blob/master/packages/cra-template-pwa/template/src/service-worker.js) into your project.